# Inherit from std::string without npos problems in DLLs

Tags: c++, string

A lot of years ago i made the mistake to inherit from std::string in DLL and put some funktions like "MakeUpper" to the string. Converting from VS2008 to VS2012 the problem whith the npos pops up. With a workaround from microsoft * i get some other DLLs working, but not DLLs which are used late-binding and have no DLLMain() function.

*[Microsoft Workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/68c23058-6dba-4eaf-a973-8d8afa1f500d/visual-2010-error-lnk2001-on-stdstringnpos)

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1600
#include <string>
const std::basic_string<char>::size_type std::basic_string<char>::npos =   (std::basic_string<char>::size_type) -1;
#endif
```

The class is declared in a DLL like this:

```
class  MYDLL_API CNyString  : public std::string
```

the errorline is this:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int const std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::npos" (?npos@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@2IB)
```

Rewriting the MyString class with an std::string as attribute does not work because it is used in several other DLLs where MyString and string functions are mixed a lot, also in function parameters. Example:

```
 void Foo(const CMyString &Param_) ..
 ...
 Foo(std::string("Hallo World")..
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you implement `toUpper` et al as non-member functions acting on `std::basic_string<T>`?

Comment: the only _true_ solution is not inheriting std::string, face it. It has no virtual destructor.

Comment: What they said. But I'm not sure what "the npos problem" is really. I mean, I see the solution, but not the problem. And isn't that basically how npos is defined in the standard lib anyway?

Comment: What happens if you inherit it `private`ly and then say `using std::string::some_member;` to make `some_member` visible? That might avoid making `npos` publicly visible, though I'm not sure if that solves the problem...

Comment: I can´t implement non-member functions to a environment with 60 DLLs and several companies who writes code with them. I just tried my last option: Implement a header only CMyString-class with no MYDLL_API (DLL export/import). This seemed to be working. Thanks.

Comment: The thing with the virtual destructor is a point. I will look after this.